# Improve cube processing time

Tags: ssas

I've got a cube with around 6 facts and 40 dimensions. Right now my cube is taking 1 and half hour to process, and most of the time is taken by 2 facts. But now the users are asking for data which should not be more then an hour old. Now I'm thinking of storing the partitions of those 2 facts table in ROLAP(right now they are MOLAP)mode. Would it help in improving the cube processing time or I should look for another approach?Also, is it going to make much difference in query performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the partitions are small, and the logic to access the ROLAP partition is fast (i. e. no complex views, etc.) the increased query time should not be dramatic. But in fact, you just should test, as there are many factors influencing performance.

Comment: @FrankPI: I've decided not to go for ROLAP mode, and instead create more partitions. One of my Fact was created on quarterly basis, and now 've divided it on monthly basis, but 'm hardly seeing any improvement. Any advice?

Comment: Why do you not create a really small partition just for the current day that is processed hourly, and its data integrated during the night into the last monthly or quarterly partition, while this current day partition will then get empty during this nightly run, prepared to be updated every hour again.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Partitions are the key to sink processing time. You have not specified how much facts you have (time-wise), but lets say you have a month worth of data. So one partition would be month - 1 latest day and the second partition would contain that latest day. You would only re-process this small partition every hour and process full cube once every day when there are no users online.

Partitions do help out when it comes to processing time.

Comment: Your last sentence is not correct. Partitions can also help with query performance: If Analysis Services can determine that only data from certain partitions is needed, it only reads the data of those partitions. If the partitions accessed are small compared to the whole measure group, this can improve performance. And ROLAP mode makes performance worse normally.